# WordPress Polylang can only use one language

Tags: multi-language, plugin-polylang

I am using Polylang in WordPress to construct my site. It worked perfectly for the first half year, while I was not actively updating the site during the time. The second language suddently not working. At the front page, if I click the second language, it was redirected to the front page of the first language. If I click the second language on pages other than the front page, it shows "It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help." When I move the front page of the second language to trash and move back, the situation changed - I click the first language at the front page, it was redirected to the front page of the second language. I can see that all pages at the backstage are normal, and I can view them from WordPress Page. However I cannot view one language using the normal url. Is there anyone can provide some guidance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! You'll need to contact Polylang's support for a solution to this, they're the ones who know their own plugin best. Questions about third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) here.